# What is the correct order of loading AngularJS files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I encountered a problem where my AngularJS webpages don't load properly sometimes. When this happens, the code in the corresponding controller does not run. It only happens rarely. I suspect that this could be due to the loading order of AngularJS files. Perhaps there are other possible causes. Please alert me if you can think of any. Below is my code showing the loading order of the html page;

```
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>        
    <script src="vendor/dialogs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="vendor/angular-translate.min.js"></script>  
    <link href="vendor/dialogs.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First Load angular library:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/dialogs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>   
<script src="vendor/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
```

After that load your controllers, services, filters, directives

```
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

Finally, now you can load your app init file

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does it matter in which order I declare each controller? How would you order a list of separate controllers and services?

Comment: No it doesn't matter.

Comment: Order as you mentioned 1)services, 2) controllers, 3)filters, 4)directives is required?

Comment: No.. it is not required.

Answer (score 7):

Although the order is correctly mentioned by Nitish,
you should consider using a script loading tools such as **require js** as mantaining the inter-dependency between libraries will get messy once you have a large no of files to include.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to order these inter-dependencies?

Comment: @rcat24 With requireJS, you do not need to worry about the ordering of the libraries that you use,as it provides API to mention each dependency for every library in particular order and depending on that,require will manage the dependencies.  As the angular controllers are mostly independent of each other,you can have any order for loading their files.But controllers are mostly dependent on services and you need to have them loaded before injecting in ctrls or directives.But if you use requireJS,you can have any order as require will create a dependency tree first and then load dependencies.