# Angular Routing is not working even after controller is defined in main page

Tags: angularjs

I have defined my controller in main page but still i keep getting this error.  [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=NavCtrl

app.module.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
```

routeConfig.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'Blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home',
            controller: 'HomeController',

        });
});
```

TestScript.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).controller('NavCtrl',
['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };

    $scope.loadHome = function () {
        $location.url('/home');
    };

    $scope.loadBlog = function () {
        $location.url('/blog');
    };

}]);


angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    console.log('inside home controller');

});

angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).controller('BlogController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    console.log('inside blog controller');

});
```

Home.html

```
<div>
    Home Navigation panel.
</div>
```

Blog.html

```
<div>
    Blog Navigation panel.
</div>
```

MainPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>



    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <!--<script src="Views/Config/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="Views/Directives/Ecommerce/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="Views/Directives/Ecommerce/directive.js"></script>-->
    <script src="TestScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/EcommerceStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <!--<my-Directive></my-Directive>-->
    <a href="#" ng-click="loadHome()">Home</a><br />
    <a href="#" ng-click="loadBlog()">Blog</a>
    <br />
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest if i am missing something or do i need to inject something to making routing work

Comment: You just need to move the `app.module.js` script below your controller scripts in `MainPage.html`. See [What is the correct order of loading AngularJS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900348/what-is-the-correct-order-of-loading-angularjs-files)

Comment: @Tyler I tried did not work for me.

Comment: Every time you call `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])` you are creating a new app module because you are passing the second parameter (an array of things to inject). Once you have registered your app module the first time, future references should just be `angular.module('myApp')` without the second parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just as the @Lex said,
 please remove `['ngRoute']` from all of the controllers in your `TestScript.js` and include/uncomment your `app.module.js` and `routeConfig.js` scripts in your `MainPage.html`

So that you may achieve something like this if it's all put together;

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]); // from app.module

angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]).config(function ($routeProvider) { // from routeConfig
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'Blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home',
            controller: 'HomeController',

        });
});


angular.module("myApp").controller('NavCtrl',
['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) { // from TestScript

    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };

    $scope.loadHome = function () {
        $location.url('/home');
    };

    $scope.loadBlog = function () {
        $location.url('/blog');
    };

}]);


angular.module("myApp").controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    console.log('inside home controller');

});

angular.module("myApp").controller('BlogController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    console.log('inside blog controller');

});
```